# Google Cloud Platform - Datastore - Python ndb API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I recently started working with the Google Cloud Platform, more precisely, with the ndb-Datastore-API. I tried to use following tutorial (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-python.git) to get used to the API.

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to import the third party library tweepy into tweet.py. Google Cloud does not support tweepy so that I had to include the library manually in a folder /lib. But how do I now import the installed tweepy (pip install -t lib tweepy)?

I basically just try to put an Entity in the Google Datastore but I cannot figure out what I did wrong.

tweet.py:

```
    # [START imports]
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
import os
import urllib
from time import *
import jinja2
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)
# [END imports]

# [START globalvar]
# Go to http://apps.twitter.com and create an app.
# The consumer key and secret will be generated for you after
consumer_key="KEY"
consumer_secret="SECRET"
# After the step above, you will be redirected to your app's page.
# Create an access token under the the "Your access token" section
access_token="TOKEN"
access_token_secret="SECRET"
# [END globalvar]

USERNAME = "@Seeed"

def getDate():
    # local Time
    lt = localtime()
    # get Date
    year, month, day = lt[0:3]
    date = "%02i.%02i.%04i" % (day,month,year)
    return date

# [START tweet_count_entity]
class TweetCount(ndb.Model):
    """A main model for representing an individual TweetCount entry."""
    date = ndb.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    tweets = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)
    user_name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)

# [END tweet_count_entity]

# [START tweet_counter]
class TweetCounter(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """
    # Create a key for the Entity
    def tweetCount_key(date):
        date = getDate()
        return ndb.Key('TweetCount', date)"""

    # Get TweetCount for actor "user_name"
    def getTweetCount(self, user_name):
        auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        user = api.get_user(user_name)
        return user.followers_count

    def get(self):
        count = self.getTweetCount(USERNAME)
        tweet_count_user_name = USERNAME
        tweet_count_tweets = count
        tweet_count = TweetCount(tweets=tweet_count_tweets, user_name=tweet_count_user_name)
        tweet_count.put()
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write("" + USERNAME + " TweetCount: " + str(count))

# [END tweet_counter]

# [START app]
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', TweetCounter),
], debug=True)
# [END app]
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

# [START handlers]
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: tweet.app
# [END handlers]

# [START libraries]
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
# [END libraries]
```

index.yaml:

```
indexes:
- kind: TweetCount
  properties:
  - name: date
  - name: tweets
  - name: user_name
```

appengine_config.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate any help and an explanation about what I did wrong.

Comment: You have a typo in your model definition: `nbd` for username. You should really run your code locally to see any errors before you deploy.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, for your support. I run my app now locally. It really helped me to figure out my first few errors. Unfortunatly, I cannot find anything at Google about how to import third party libraries inside the python code. I added the appengine_config.py but struggle to import tweepy into tweet.py.

Comment: Retagged - this is more of an App Engine question rather than a Cloud Datastore questions since it's about code/library deployment to App Engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `tweet.py` and `app.yaml`, I can see the 2 things that may be the reason you cannot yet use **tweepy** in your Python application.  For the sake of being through, I'll document the complete process.

### Acquire tweepy library

As **Tweepy** is a [third party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) and not a library that ships with Google App Engine, we have to package it with our Python application as you've already suggested with [`pip install --target lib tweepy`](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#use-pip-for-installing).  The directory specified after the `--target` option is where the third party library will be downloaded.

### Vendor in the third-party directory

Now that we've downloaded the third party library, Python must be made to search this `lib` directory when attempting to import modules.  This can be done as you've shown, using an `appengine_config.py` file in your application directory as indicated in [Installing a library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_library) like so:

```python
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

### Import third-party module in the application

Python will now look in the `lib` directory when attempting to import modules.  Thus, we add our import statement where appropriate in our application code (e.g.: `tweet.py`):

```python
import tweepy
```

***This import is not currently found in your `tweet.py` example.***

### Ensure tweepy's dependencies are also imported

Note that **tweepy** when imported will attempt to import the **ssl** module so it must be included in the `libraries` section of your `app.yaml` like so:

```yaml
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

***This too, was not in your example `app.yaml`.***

With the above, one should be able to successfully deploy a python GAE application which properly imports **tweepy**.  Note that I've not actively tested any of **tweepy**'s features, but merely imported it successfully.  Should you be seeing any errors with the above examples, I would suggested also including the following in your question:

- App Engine SDK version
- Python version
- pip version
- Stack trace of the error you are receiving when deploying or serving a HTTP response